# What personal information, if any, can be gleaned from a Microsoft APPCRASH problem signature?

Tags: windows, privacy, identification, microsoft

I am trying to debug an "APPCRASH" problem event for a program running on Microsoft Windows 7.

When this happens a problem signature is presented, like this example from [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/368593/appcrash-when-trying-to-install-skype):

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   SkypeSetupFull.exe
Application Version:    5.5.0.124
Application Timestamp:  4e96cbf7
Fault Module Name:  ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7600.16385
Fault Module Timestamp: 4a5bdadb
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   0006a7c9
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  7177
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

There are [quite a few questions with similar reports](https://superuser.com/search?q=appcrash).

I note that the signature includes Locale ID and OS Version and was wondering what the information security risks are for revealing this online. Specifically, what personal information can be obtained, if any? I'm guessing not much... am I right?